# Converting a PDF file consisting of tables into text document containings tables in Python

Tags: python, converters, pypdf

I have this pdf file that consists of general tables consisting of names,address,phone number,fax number. I want is :

[image: Table]

1) read this file and get the content of each row and put it in data base.
  i.e get the name from corresponding name column of the pdf file and store it in database. and so on with address, phone etc.

the main problem is whenever I am reading the pdf file and converting it into text file (As I dont't know any other way to use the data directly without converting it first to text file) the text output is completely messed up that is the format and spacing is not preserved. Please suggest a new way to do this or what can be done in the following code:

```
import pyPdf
def getPDFContent(path):
    f=open("C:\\Doctor's Data\\delhi\\hospital_delhi1.txt","w")
    content = ""
    text=""
    s=""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content = pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n\n"
        text+=content
        tokens=content.split("Fax")
        print len(tokens)
        for t in tokens:
            print t #general check
    print s        
    f.close()    
    return text


getPDFContent("C:\\Doctor's Data\\delhi\\hospital_delhi1.pdf")
```

adding up my output is (Messed Up) :

S.NONAME OF THE HOSPITAL/CLINIC ADDRESS OF THE HOSPITAL/CLINIC PHONE NO. FAX NOLIST OF HOSPITALS AT DELHI59Walia Nursing HomeG.60, Laxmi Nagar, Shakarpur, DelhiDr.A.S.Dave - 2224858560Metro Heart InstituteSector A, Faridabad
:226358961Ayushman HospitalSector-XII, Dwarka, New Delhi42811114/15/16/18
: 28081723, 4553700163Mohan Eye Institute11-B, Ganga Ram Hospital Marg, New Delhi-6064Shroff Eye CentreKasturba Gandhi Marg, New DelhiReimbursement on CGHS rates without credit basis65Rockland HospitalB-33-34, Qutab Institutional Area, New Delhi66National Heart  Institute49, Community Centre, East of Kailash

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some already existing python packages:

- **[pdftables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdftables/0.0.4)** - ([Github](https://github.com/okfn/pdftables))
- **[pdftable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdftable)**